# How to update a raster layer's statistics (min/max) in PyQGIS after changing its data?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis

I want to alter a raster layer with Python code and update the style afterwards. The style part is out of reach because I encountered the following problem:

I added a Float64 raster layer to my project using the "Create constant raster layer" processing tool. The layer is in my project's table of contents, named "Constant".

Then I run this script in the Python console:

```
import struct

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Constant')[0]
data_provider = layer.constDataProvider()
block = data_provider.block(1, layer.extent(), layer.width(), layer.height())

new_data = struct.pack("dd", *[-99, 99])  # two double values
block.setData(new_data)

data_provider.setEditable(enabled=True)
data_provider.writeBlock(block, 1)
data_provider.setEditable(enabled=False)
```

The TIF file is rewritten now. If I open it manually, I see the new values in the first two pixels in the top left of the image.

But the "Constant" layer that was already in my ToC and on which I operated, still shows the same old constant value as its min and max values. I tried setting the "Min / Max Value Settings"' "Accuracy" to "Actual (slower)" with no success. I also tried `data_provider.reload()` and `layer.triggerRepaint()` without success.

[image: Altered layer that was in the ToC already]
[image: Layer file loaded the project manually afterwards]

I do not want to set the min and max values manually, but have QGIS execute whatever it does when I set the "Min / Max Value Settings"' "Accuracy" to "Actual (slower)".

How do I make QGIS recognize the new data in the layer and update its statistics?

Comment: What does your code do, I have not seen `struct` before

Comment: I used `struct` to pack two double values into bytes. Is there a nicer way to do that in pyqgis (maybe using Qt's functions?)?

Answer (score 5):

Interesting work!

The minimum and maximum values are configured with a QgsContrastEnhancement assigned to a renderer.

Try incorporating this code with a singleBandGray symbology

```
capa=iface.activeLayer()
provider=capa.dataProvider()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, extent)
min = stats.minimumValue
max = stats.maximumValue

renderer=capa.renderer() #current renderer
myType = renderer.dataType(1)

GrayRenderer = QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer(provider,1) #create a new renderer
contrast_enhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum
myEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(contrast_enhancement,True)
myEnhancement.setMinimumValue(min)   #Set the minimum value you want
myEnhancement.setMaximumValue(max)   #Put the maximum value you want 
capa.setRenderer(GrayRenderer)
capa.renderer().setContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)
capa.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Thanks! I do not want to set the min and max values manually though, but have QGIS execute whatever it does when I set the "Min / Max Value Settings"' "Accuracy" to "Actual (slower)". Well, if that it is at all easily triggerable from pyqgis. Otherwise I would have to care about NODATA etc myself and probably write something slow.